# Problem about Choosing a Suitable Origin

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

[image]

The part I'm not getting is how we can choose "a suitable choice of origin" such that $\textbf{a}$ can be written as a vector in the direction of the magnetic field; specifically, here's my thought process: if we view $\dot{\textbf{x}}(t)$ as a function of time and likewise view ${\textbf{x}}(t)$ as a function of time, then we have:
$$\textbf{a}=\dot{\textbf{x}}(0)-\alpha\textbf{x}(0)\times{\textbf{n}}$$
Then I thought I should choose the origin such that $\textbf{x}(0)=\textbf{0}$ so that $\textbf{a}$ is simply the initial velocity of the particle, but the question never states that the particle is initially travelling along the magnetic field, so I'm not sure what to do about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have proven the part that
$$
\dot {\mathbf x} = \alpha \mathbf x \times \mathbf n + \mathbf g t + \mathbf a,
$$
let's change the origin $\mathbf x_1=\mathbf x - \mathbf d$:
$$
\dot{\mathbf x}_1 = \alpha (\mathbf x_1 +\mathbf d)\times \mathbf n + \mathbf g t + \mathbf a = \alpha \mathbf x_1\times \mathbf n + \mathbf g t + (\mathbf a + \alpha \mathbf d \times \mathbf n),
$$

Vector $\alpha \mathbf d \times \mathbf n$ can be any vector perpendicular to $\mathbf n$. Thus, if $\mathbf a$ has a component perpendicular to $\mathbf n$, we can remove it with the proper $\mathbf d$. Indeed, select $\mathbf d = \alpha^{-1}\mathbf a \times \mathbf n$, then:
$$
\mathbf a_1 = \mathbf a+\alpha(\alpha^{-1}\mathbf a \times \mathbf n)\times\mathbf n = \mathbf a - \mathbf a (\mathbf n\cdot \mathbf n)+\mathbf n(\mathbf a\cdot \mathbf n) = (\mathbf a\cdot \mathbf n)\mathbf n
$$
clearly a vector collinear with $\mathbf n$.